# SQL Calculate hours over night with static date

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'm writing Queries on a system someone else installed, so tables can not be changed here.

problem:
I have a table where i've got Date, timeIN and timeOUT
take the following records;

```
     date               |       timeIN      | timerOUT
-------------------------------------------------
2016-01-01 00:00:00.00  | 2000-01-01 07:00  | 2000-01-01 15:00       DATEDIFF = 8H
2016-01-02 00:00:00.00  | 2000-01-01 07:00  | 2000-01-01 15:00       DATEDIFF = 8H
2016-01-05 00:00:00.00  | 2000-01-01 23:00  | 2000-01-01 07:00       DATEDIFF = -16H
```

How can i get DATEDIFF = 8H from record number 3?
The problem here is that all timeIN and timeOUT stamps have the same dummy date.

Comment: Why this question is up-voted ?what is so special about this question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression inside the `DATEDIFF` function:

```
SELECT
    Diff = 
        DATEDIFF(
            HOUR, 
            timeIn, 
            CASE 
                WHEN timeOut < timeIn THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, timeOut) 
                ELSE timeOut 
            END
        )
FROM tbl
```

This will add one day on `timeOut` if it's less than the `timeIn`.